# Semi empirical mass formula

Tags: python, physics

I'm new to coding, I was given this assignment in my computational physics class, :[class assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5oIn.jpg)

This is the code I made for it:

```
A = int(input("please enter the atomic mass"))
Z = int(input("please enter the atomic number"))

def semi_empirical_mass_formula(A,Z):

    a1 = 15.8
    a2 = 18.3
    a3 = 0.714
    a4 = 23.2
    afive = [-12.0,12.0,0.0]

    if A%2 == 0 and Z%2 != 0:
        a5=afive[0]

    if A%2 and Z%2 == 0:
        a5=afive[1]

    if A%2 != 0:
        a5=afive[2]


    return (a1*A-a2*A**(2/3))-((a3*Z**2)/A**(1/3))-((a4*(A-2*Z)**2)/A)+((-12.0)/A**(1/2))

print (semi_empirical_mass_formula(A,Z))
```

As you might be able to see, it does not work and I don't know why the answer it gives me is 324.724. The Answer should be ~500

I'm interested in learning, my professor encourages us to ask questions to communities of coders like this one. Please include an explanation of how to fix it. this last part would benefit me greatly as I'm a very inexperienced at coding.

EDIT: I also used the "//" for the division, when I do that the answer it gives me is 326.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your indentation is definitely off. Please fix it, then we can see if the problem is someplace else. Also, please elaborate on "it does not work". Read [ask] first. Also also, `num1 and num2==0` doesn't do what you think it does. I hope this is python 3, otherwise `1/3` is also not what you think it is;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you for letting me know of those problems I had, I have edited them on the question itself and code. However, I'm still not getting the right answer. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I see you've fixed your indentation. We're getting closer. You still haven't specified the exact nature of the problem; I assume the "wrong answer" is the problem. Two possible things remain, which I hinted at in my previous comment: 1. integer division can be a problem if you use python 2; you should be careful (and use python 3) in this case. And 2. check what `if A%2 and Z%2 == 0:` does. Hint: it doesn't evaluate to `True` if both are even numbers.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I changed the statement to be 'if A%2 == 0 and Z%2 == 0:' still not correct. it might be the first thing. could you elaborate, please? I am not sure what the problem would be with integer operations.

Comment: I don't know Python, but I know that when you write new code it's good to start with something simple that works perfectly, then build up slowly. Try writing a program that returns 10/2. When that works, try a program that tests whether 6 and 8 are both even. Small steps.

Comment: You forgot `a5` in the last term of your equation, it's hard-wired `-12`........

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need this still, 4.5 years later, but to anyone else who has this problem currently and is looking for help, here's what I did to answer Exercise 2.10 a. in Python Programming for Physicists (sometimes also called Computational Physics) by Mark Newman.

```
A = float(input("Please enter the atomic mass number "))
Z = float(input("Please enter the atomic number "))

a1 = 15.8
a2 = 18.3
a3 = .714
a4 = 23.2

if A % 2 == 1:
    a5 = 0
elif A % 2 == 0 and Z % 2 == 0 :
    a5 = 12.0
else:
    a5 = -12.0
    
B = a1*A - a2*(A**(2/3)) - a3*(Z**2)/(A**(1/3)) - a4*((A-2*Z)**2)/A + a5/(A**(1/2))

print("The nuclear binding energy is: ", round(B, 2))
```